# Filtering services by intent-filter category

Tags: android, android-source

I'm learning android by writing a launcher on top of AOSP and looking in the ways to get all services from installed packages that have certain `category` in their `intent-filter`

My current approach is

```java
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
int flags = PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS | PackageManager.GET_SERVICES;
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(flags);

for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Installed package: " + packageInfo.packageName);

  for (ServiceInfo service : packageInfo.services) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service: " + service.packageName);
    // ???
  }
}
```

An example of services defined in `Manifest.xml`:

```
<service
    android:name=".ComplicationIntentService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="my.intent.CATEGORY" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Sadly `ServiceInfo` object doesn't seem to contain information about the intent filters and a few searches seems to hint that this is not implemented

Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: That `<intent-filter>` seems incomplete. But, you can try calling `queryIntentServices()` on `PackageManager`, with an `Intent` that should match the `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: great, I'll give it a go, what do you mean by incomplete `intent-filter`?

Comment: An implicit `Intent` usually has an action string. However, any `Intent` with an action string should not match that `<intent-filter>`. That `<intent-filter>` should match an `Intent` with *just* that category, nothing else (no action, no `Uri`, no MIME type).

Comment: gotcha, I'll look up a proper way to define a service. Thanks for clarifying